# Training only the mixed8 and mixed9 layers of InceptionV3, why does my model summary reference lower mixed layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I want to train only mixed8 and mixed9 layers of inceptionV3.

I wrote this code:

```
 from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
 pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape=(299,299,3),
                                      include_top = False,
                                      weights = 'imagenet')

  last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('mixed8') #only use layers including and above mixed8
  print('last layer output shape:', last_layer.output_shape)
  last_output = last_layer.output    
  x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)

  x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
  x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)

  x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
  x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)

  x = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
  x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
  
  x = layers.Dense(5,activation='softmax')(x)

  model = tf.keras.Model(pre_trained_model.input,x)
  print(model.summary())
```

And when I print model.summary(), I can see lines like:

```
 mixed0 (Concatenate)           (None, 35, 35, 256)  0           ['activation_287[0][0]',         
                                                                  'activation_289[0][0]',         
                                                                  'activation_292[0][0]',         
                                                                  'activation_293[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_297 (Conv2D)            (None, 35, 35, 64)   16384       ['mixed0[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_297 (Batch  (None, 35, 35, 64)  192         ['conv2d_297[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 activation_297 (Activation)    (None, 35, 35, 64)   0           ['batch_normalization_297[0][0]']
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_295 (Conv2D)            (None, 35, 35, 48)   12288       ['mixed0[0][0]']
```

and....

```
mixed1 (Concatenate)           (None, 35, 35, 288)  0           ['activation_294[0][0]',         
                                                                  'activation_296[0][0]',         
                                                                  'activation_299[0][0]',         
                                                                  'activation_300[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_304 (Conv2D)            (None, 35, 35, 64)   18432       ['mixed1[0][0]']
```

In the output (among others, e.g. mixed3 is also listed in the model.summary()). I guess I'm not properly calling only mixed8 and 9 in the output, since the model.summary() references mixed0, mixed1 etc?

Could someone show me how to change the code above (I guess in the `last_layer` line) to only train on mixed8 and 9?

Just for clarity, I then call the model like this:

```
  history = model.fit(train_generator,
                      epochs=1000, 
                      validation_data=validation_generator,
                      batch_size=32,
                      callbacks = callbacks_list,
                      verbose=1
                      )
```

using data (train_generator and validation_generator) that I developed using `ImageDataGenerator`

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to do? Since passing pre_trained_model.input to your model includes all layers *until* the `mixed8` layer.

Comment: Oh I wanted the opposite, I wanted to only train mixed 8 and 9.

Comment: Sorry I just added an edit to make it clearer. I used ImageDataGenerator to make a train_generator and validation_generator, then I developed the model as described above, and then I fit the model to the train and validation generators using model.fit that I have now added to the above code for clarity.

Comment: Ok, I will ask a bit differently... do you want to use the `InceptionV3` model starting from the `mixed8` layer till the final layer? If yes, what would be the input to the `mixed8` layer, which has a very specific input shape?

Comment: Please let me know if I'm not answering this correctly, in which case I apologise, I appreciate the help. (1) Yes, I do want to use the ```InceptionV3``` model starting at ```mixed8``` until the final layer. (2) Maybe I'm mis-understanding and I can't do this: I was hoping to re-shape the ```train_generator``` data to (299,299) and read that in (which is what I think I do/thought I was doing in the above code).

Comment: Yeah but it is pretty complicated because the mixed layers contain inputs from different layers..meaning the `InceptionV3` model is not entirely sequential